# objective c explode NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i need something equivalent of this in objective c

```
list($var1,$var2) = explode("=",$array);
```

i tried

```
NSArray *stringArray = [postString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (NSString* str in stringArray) {
     NSArray *keyvalue = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
     [postParam setValue:[keyvalue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[keyvalue objectAtIndex:0]];
     [postData addObject:postParam];
}
```

but my app crash with message

> <__NSDictionaryI 0x727abc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key XY

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[postParam setValue:[keyvalue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[keyvalue objectAtIndex:0]]];
```